# error on installing rgbdslam_freiburg

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
pc:~/hydro_workspace_test/sandbox$ rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg/
```

when i run this code in terminal   (ROS_HYDRO,ubuntu 13.04)
i see this error

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
```

Missing resource rgbdslam_freiburg/
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/masoud/hydro_workspace_test/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg
ROS path [2]=/home/masoud/hydro_workspace_test/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143346/error-on-installing-rgbdslam_freiburg/) by [masoudpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5391/masoudpz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to install rgbdslam for fuerte on hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masoudpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5391/masoudpz/) on 2014-03-28**:
thanks for response.is there any link for rgbdslam_freiburg in hydro?or an alternative way?how can i install rgbdslam_freiburg on hydro?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-04-07**:
I am currently preparing a release for hydro. Send me an e-mail if you would like to test a beta version.